# how to view text files with line length more than 1024?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've created text file which contains 100 000 of 'a' and doesn't contain "new line" symbols.
I've placed it here if this is important https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49126809/abc.txt

I've tried "Notepad" and "Lister from TotalCommander" editors and both of them limit line length to 1024. But I don't need to wrap text at all, i.e. a want to see just one very long line.

Is it possible? What editor to use?

Comment: If you only wanted to view the file (not edit it), Firefox displays it as one line. So does IE8. Chrome adds a lot of line breaks, and Opera adds a few (less than Chrome, but still has some). Actually, there's some JavaScript trick to make a document editable in a browser, which can then be saved... (of course, Akash's suggestion of Notepad++ is easier, this is mostly out of curiosity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ opens the file fine, a single very long line

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.3.html

Use the "no installation required" version to test if its OK for your needs and install it if its OK